# Report labels match a dropdown in report builders

Tags: tableau-api

I have a report that is designed to allow users who aren't proficient in Tableau visualize data in the form of a bar graph. There are some drop downs on the side that allow them to select some dimensions. These dimensions then populate the graph. The labels in the graph, however, do not match the dimension name selected, and I was curious how to do this. So for instance on the right hand side Dimension 1 is set to *Item Subcategory*, and I'd like it to say that in the graph as well, instead of being labeled *Dimension 1*.
[image]

The drop downs on the right are generated from this code in the dimension itself:
[image]

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this would be to hide the column headers on the sheet itself, or edit their aliases to just a bunch of spaces so it appears blank.

You can then create a sheet with the Dimension 1 parameter on the Text shelf, formatted to look like a column header (or formatted however you want it to look), and add that sheet to the dashboard as a floating sheet. Repeat for the other two dimension parameters, position the sheet above the column so it looks like the header, and there you go! Whenever the parameter changes, the column header will change to match too.

I would note that this only works if the sheet is on a fixed-size dashboard, since floating sheets don't usually play nice with auto-sizing dashboards.